# SQL Insert multilingual characters

Tags: asp.net, sql, localization, globalization, multilingual

I am trying to create a table in my MS SQL database for Languages.
I want to store an English name of Language and a local name of language in the database.
i.e.
**Language, Language(local)**
English, English
German, Deutsch
Italian, Italiano
Japanese, 日本語
...
...

I have 279 languages that I want to import, but when I import it shows '?????' for some like japanese, Russian and arabic etc
The database Collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

I would also like advise on multilingual websites; if i have a database of product descriptions and I want to have translation in multiple languages, should I go for separate databases or Can I have translation in one databse? (I prefer not to duplicate data!). Anything else to make sure users are able to write comments in different languages (char encoding on web?) and can be stored in database.

***Thanks to an advise I have managed to import data but, I cannot select and view correctly and therefore cannot verify if import was successful; I am getting following results on select:***
[image: Select language result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you need is nvarchar

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186939.aspx

EDIT:

quering

```
select * from table where column = N'abc'
```

Comment: And don't expect to see the local language characters correctly in SQL Management Studio. The character set there is limited. You will have to verify the values through your app.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has a pretty solid infrastructure for handling localization. Much easier than rolling your own multi-language support.

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/localization.aspx